# Django add User and Listing model to a Watchlist model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to add a Listing model for an eCommerce app to a Wishlist model, but I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong.

I referenced this post in order to create a Wishlist model and link it to my User and Listing models via a Foreign key for each.
[Wishlist post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63403309/watchlist-system-on-django)

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


app_name = "auctions"
urlpatterns = [

    # Listing paths
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login/", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout/", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register/", views.register, name="register"),
    path("addlisting/", views.add_listing, name="add_listing"),
    path("viewlisting/<int:listing_id>", views.view_listing, name="view_listing"),

    # Watchlist paths
    path("watchlist_add/<int:listing_id>", views.watchlist_add, name="watchlist_add"),

]
```

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime


# Categories
categories = [
    ('misc', 'misc'),
    ('computers','computers'),
    ('toys','toys'),
    ('pets','pets'),
    ('beauty','beauty'),
    ('video games','video games'),
    ('food','food'),
    ('clothing','clothing'),
]


ACTIVE_CHOICES = [
    ('Yes', 'Yes'),
    ('No', 'No'),
]

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Listing(models.Model):
    listing_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="owner")

    listing_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    listing_description = models.TextField(max_length=1200)
    listing_img = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=250)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    starting_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, default=1.00)

    # From above categories list
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=categories, default='misc')
    # From active or inactive list
    active_flag = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ACTIVE_CHOICES, default="Yes", verbose_name="active listing")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']


    def __str__(self):
        return f"Name: {self.listing_title}, Price: ${self.starting_price}, Posted By: {self.listing_owner}"


class Watchlist(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.item}"
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def view_listing(request, listing_id):
    listing = get_object_or_404(Listing, pk=listing_id)
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, "auctions/view_listing.html" , { "listing": listing})
    else:
        try:
            form = ListingForm(request.POST, instance=listing)
            form.save()
            return redirect("auctions:index")
        except ValueError:
            return render(request, "auctions/view_listing.html", {"listing": listing, "form": form})


@login_required
def watchlist_add(request, listing_id):
    listing = get_object_or_404(Listing, pk=listing_id)
    obj, created = Watchlist.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, item_id=listing_id)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("auctions:index"))
```

view_listing.html

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %} {% block body %}
<h1 class="display-3 text-center mb-5">{{ listing.listing_title }}</h1>
<div class="container d-flex">
    <figure class="figure">
        {% if listing.listing_img %}
        <img src="{{ listing.listing_img }}" alt="{{ listing.listing_title }}" title="{{ listing.listing_title }}"> {% else %}
        <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/guez/image/upload/v1606759078/cs50_commerce_project/default_image.jpg" alt="default image" title="default image"> {% endif %}
        <figcaption class="figure - caption">Listed By: {{ listing.listing_owner|capfirst }}</figcaption>
    </figure>


    <div class="container m-4">
        <p class="display-4">${{ listing.starting_price }}</p>
        <hr>
        <p class="">Description: {{ listing.listing_description }}</p>
        <p class="figure-caption">Category: {{ listing.category|capfirst }}</p>
        <small></small>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="{% url 'auctions:watchlist_add' listing.pk %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ listing.pk }}" name="listing">
            <input type="submit" value="Add To Watchlist" class="btn btn-outline-warning">
        </form>
        <!--<a href="{% url 'auctions:watchlist_add' listing.pk %}" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Add To Watchlist</a>-->
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Before there are any items on my wishlist, I go to view_listing.html and hit the 'Add To Watchlist' button. I then get an AttributeError that reads "AttributeError: 'Listing' object has no attribute 'remove'". Here's the stack trace:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 07, 2020 - 00:08:42
Django version 3.1, using settings 'commerce.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8080/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[07/Dec/2020 00:08:44] "GET /admin/auctions/watchlist/2/delete/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5409
[07/Dec/2020 00:08:45] "POST /admin/auctions/watchlist/2/delete/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[07/Dec/2020 00:08:45] "GET /admin/auctions/watchlist/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5215
[07/Dec/2020 00:08:46] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3187
[07/Dec/2020 00:08:48] "GET /admin/auctions/watchlist/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5215
[07/Dec/2020 00:08:48] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3187
[07/Dec/2020 00:08:51] "GET /admin/auctions/watchlist/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5215
[07/Dec/2020 00:08:51] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3187
[07/Dec/2020 00:09:01] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3962
[07/Dec/2020 00:09:03] "GET /viewlisting/8 HTTP/1.1" 200 2350
Name: Sega Genesis, Price: $1.00, Posted By: guez already in cart.
Internal Server Error: /watchlist_add/8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/project2/commerce/auctions/views.py", line 108, in watchlist_add
    obj.listings.remove(listing)
AttributeError: 'Listing' object has no attribute 'remove'
[07/Dec/2020 00:09:06] "POST /watchlist_add/8 HTTP/1.1" 500 73233
```

I want to add the item to Wishlist via the `watchlist_add` function and then pass that new Wishlist object to the `view_listing` function in order to determine whether the button should or should not exist in the `view_listing.html` template if the item is already in `request.user` 's Watchlist.

?[image: Object added to wishlist]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your code seems having a logic problem. You `get_or_create` a `WatchList` object, and you test if that `obj` is in the `WatchList` or not. The `obj` will always be in your `WatchList.objects.all()`, because it was there before or you just created.
2. 

```
obj.listings.remove(listing)
```

According to [django doc about remove()][1], you should use it the following way:

```
obj.listing_set.remove(obj)
```

3. together, how about something like:

```
@login_required
def watchlist_add(request, listing_id):
    listing = get_object_or_404(Listing, pk=listing_id)

    already_existed = Watchlist.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, item=listing).exists()

    if already_existed:
        # do something:
        # return ... 
    else:
        Watchlist.objects.create(user=request.user, item=listing)
        # do something
        # return ....
```

Or you can still use get_or_create...

```
@login_required
def watchlist_add(request, listing_id):
    listing = get_object_or_404(Listing, pk=listing_id)
    obj, created = Watchlist.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, item_id=listing_id)

    if created: # means it was a new one
         # do something
         # return ...
    else:
         # do something, maybe delete whatever button you want to delete, 
         # maybe return a variable like below
         # and in template you have {% if delete_button %} 
         # delete_button = True
         # return ....


  [1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.remove
```

Comment: Thanks, ha-neul. When I add an extra underscore to "listings_id" and use "listings__id", I get a 'RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /watchlist_add/8 Watchlist has no listings' error. Also, the object that is saved is simpy just a "-" instead of "Name: Sega Genesis, Price: $1.00, Posted By: guez" object that gets passed when I only use one underscore in "listings_id"

Comment: It's listings                                                                                                              ```class Watchlist(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    listings = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)```

Comment: Hi, sorry for earlier confusion caused by my answer. I think what you have is right, though, ```user=request.user, listings=listing``` should be enough. The other two pionts from my original answer are still valid.

Comment: Thanks and it's okay. I changed "listings" to "item". I think it just makes more sense because there are too many references to "listing" in the code as it is. I updated the code in my views.py watchlist_add and models.py based on what you mentioned about the obj always being in watchlist.objects.all(), which makes sense. It seems to add the item to the watchlist properly so I'll have to figure out how to get the Watchlist item attributes in order to display it in a watchlist and make the "Add to watchlist" button unavailable if that item exists in the request.user Watchlist.

Comment: updated my answer, still not very clear on what you are trying to achive, but the code I provided should get you started somehow.